# How to convert a date time string input as formatted date time string in Joda date time

Tags: java, jodatime

I have wrote a function to convert date time string into formatted date time string and return the result.

input date time String =`2015-12-16 12:27:07.0`
out put date time String= `02/20/2016 12:32 PM`

```
public static String convertDateToCustomFormat(String dateString) {
        DateFormat dbDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        DateFormat uiDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String date = null;
        try {
            date = uiDateFormat.format(dbDateFormat.parse(dateString));

        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return date;
    }
```

the above function is working fine.But i used `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` for formatting the string.I tried to convert same functionality into `joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat` but i got a error message saying

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "2015-12-16 12:27:07.0" is malformed at ".0"
```

**Here is my new function using joda date time**

input date time String =`2015-12-16 12:27:07.0`
***out put date time should be like this*** = `02/20/2016 12:32 PM`

```
public static String convertDateToCustomFormat(String dateString) {
        DateTimeFormatter dbDateFormat = DateTimeFormat
                .forPattern(("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss .aa"));
        DateTimeFormatter uiDateFormat = DateTimeFormat
                .forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        DateTime date = null;

        date = dbDateFormat.parseDateTime(dateString);

        return uiDateFormat.print(date);
    }
```

Please let me know where i did the mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this, FYI [DatetimeFormat](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

```
public static String convertDateToCustomFormat(String dateString) {
    DateTimeFormatter dbDateFormat = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern(("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S"));
    DateTimeFormatter uiDateFormat = DateTimeFormat
            .forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
    DateTime date = null;

    date = dbDateFormat.parseDateTime(dateString);

    return uiDateFormat.print(date);
}
```